# Dealing with new users using pre-made comments

Tags: discussion, comment, new-users

I recently got access to the review queue, and am able to see new users' posts. A lot of the time I see that a user hasn't done something correctly (e.g. left out context, didn't wasn't clear, evidently didn't read the site rules, etc.).

Of course the review queue is meant to be able to find such posts much more easily, but I was wondering: would it be possible comment on these posts with pre-made comments? One example for someone who didn't show any working or thoughts in the question is:

- Hello, welcome to Stack Exchange! We are a community of *helpers* who help others out with math problems. As you didn't write anything about why this problem is difficult, what you have tried and what exactly you need help with, please add in some more information in your so that we actually can help you.

And then if needed, this could be copied and pasted to any new posts which needed this type of attention. This would save time, and also be a means to directly communicate with the new user and help them onto the right direction, as opposed to their having to find out themselves (which *is* the point of commenting on new users' posts).

Maybe we could even have a page for reviewers from which they can copy the appropriate comment (and modify it if needed) and then comment it on the post.

Comment: [This collection of comment templates](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, that's great. Can't believe I missed that. Do reviewers use this?

Comment: Just don't go on "automatic pilot" too much (what I call "rubber-stamping," a comment, which is all too easy to do without anything in the way of a proper review. Also, at least in my experience, personalizing a message or comment helps in a number of ways: it forces the comment-maker to amend any "generic post" to apply to the situation at hand, and just as important, it comes across as more genuine. I can smell a generic comment a mile away, and trust me, so can many of our askers!

Comment: Also, at least in my experience, personalizing a message or comment helps in a number of ways: it forces the comment-maker to amend any "generic post" to apply to the situation at hand, and just as important, it comes across as more genuine. I can smell a generic comment a mile away, and trust me, so can many of our askers! – amWhy just now   edit

Comment: @amWhy yes yes, absolutely correct! Generic comments definitely can come off as sounding very robotic to users – and that's why they might ignore them or not pay as much attention. That's much harder to do when you've got someone clearly talking to you directly! ;) thanks (as always) for the suggestion!

Comment: @SkeletonBow "Generic comments definitely can come off as sounding very robotic to users – and that's why they might ignore them or not pay as much attention. That's much harder to do when you've got someone clearly talking to you directly!"  Exactly! Cheers!